# Unity3D Black screen capturing screenshot

Tags: c#, image, texture2d, unity-game-engine

I am taking screenshot using

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width,height);
Rect textureRect = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
tex.ReadPixels(textureRect,0,0);
tex.Apply();
```

It works fine. But when I apply an Image Effect on the camera such as blur or bloom provided in Unity Standard Assets the screenshot captured is black. I do not understand why. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Application.CaptureScreenshot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html) to take a screenshot.

```
Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot.png");
```

If you want to display it ingame, i would recommend using a [RenderTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html), which I think is available for free since Unity5.

Comment: I want to take screenshot of particular area on the screen which I specify to the ReadPixels method. Application.CaptureScreenshot takes the screenshot of the entire camera. Regarding RenderTexture, I cannot use it. I am using Camera only for the background image, I have to place several items over it which are placed using UGUI introduced in Unity 4.6. These items have canvas of render mode Screen Space Overlay. I do not want to use a separate Camera for these items.

Comment: I did it using RenderTexture. I assigned a RenderTexture to targetTexture of the Camera and showed this RenderTexture as a RawImage on my Screen Overlay Canvas. Then took the screenhot and its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling it on `OnPostRender()` in any component.

Also you could run your capturing code in: `Camera.OnRenderImage(RenderTexture,RenderTexture)`

This method is called by Unity3D engine after all rendering is done and we have finall image on screen.

You need to create component for it and attach it to the camera.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnRenderImage.html

Comment: Both of these methods keep on calling infinitely.